# How do I use Medical Packs/Regain Health?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've perused through the manual and can't figure out how to use medical packs to regain health.  There was an on-screen tip, that I missed, that I think explained how.  (I feel dumb for asking.)

Comment: Are you referring to the ops survival packs in multiplayer which restore your health and shields? Also, which platform?

Comment: Xbox-360 Single Player

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shepard can fully restore his health by using Unity. In this iteration, it is a combination of Unity (From the previous two games) and the First Aid skill from Mass Effect the first.

Extra medi-gel now gives experience instead of credits, so there's no reason to be stingy.

The other big difference is that you do not *have* to use Unity to revive your squadmates - if you get to their position, you can revive them manually without expending medigel.

Finally, if Shepard has lost less than a full section of health, it will recover to full when his shields do, but this will never go beyond the current health pip.